# How Do I Use WkHtmlToXSharp in C#

Tags: c#, html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I've read a lot about WkHtmlToXSharp (wrapper for wkhtmltopdf) so I downloaded it.  The one page that appears to be the only documentation states you only need the wkhtmltosharp.dll, but I can't find it in the file I downloaded.  It appears to be several projects, and the thing that looks like a DLL in the Libs/Win64 folder won't load into my project.

I'd GREATLY appreciate it if someone could point me to some instructions, and maybe some basic samples.
I need to know where the .DLL is, what namespace to use, and general usage syntax to convert a HTML file to PDF.

THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static string ConvertHTMLtoPDF(string htmlFullPath, string pageSize, string orientation)
{
   string pdfUrl = htmlFullPath.Replace(".html", ".pdf");

   try
   {
       #region USING WkHtmlToXSharp.dll
       //IHtmlToPdfConverter converter = new WkHtmlToPdfConverter();
       IHtmlToPdfConverter converter = new MultiplexingConverter();

       converter.GlobalSettings.Margin.Top = "0cm";
       converter.GlobalSettings.Margin.Bottom = "0cm";
       converter.GlobalSettings.Margin.Left = "0cm";
       converter.GlobalSettings.Margin.Right = "0cm";
       converter.GlobalSettings.Orientation = (PdfOrientation)Enum.Parse(typeof(PdfOrientation), orientation);
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageSize))
           converter.GlobalSettings.Size.PageSize = (PdfPageSize)Enum.Parse(typeof(PdfPageSize), pageSize);

       converter.ObjectSettings.Page = htmlFullPath;
       converter.ObjectSettings.Web.EnablePlugins = true;
       converter.ObjectSettings.Web.EnableJavascript = true;
       converter.ObjectSettings.Web.Background = true;
       converter.ObjectSettings.Web.LoadImages = true;
       converter.ObjectSettings.Load.LoadErrorHandling = LoadErrorHandlingType.ignore;

       Byte[] bufferPDF = converter.Convert();

       System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(pdfUrl, bufferPDF);

       converter.Dispose();

       #endregion
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
   }

   return pdfUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WkHtmlToXSharp does not have a 64bit version at this stage, you need to use the 32bit version.

You should find WkHtmlToXSharp.dll somewhere in the package.

```
using WkHtmlToXSharp;
IHtmlToPdfConverter htmlToPdfConverter = new MultiplexingConverter();       
htmlToPdfConverter.ObjectSettings.Load.LoadErrorHandling = LoadErrorHandlingType.ignore;
htmlToPdfConverter.Convert(viewHtml);
```